# Read only given line from text file?

Tags: c++, string, file-io

Is there a way in C++ to grab a random number up to a given size then read that line from a text file? Without having to step through all the lines? I've got this which just prints out line by line:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("words.txt");
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
        while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
            printf("\n");
            myReadFile >> output;
            cout<<output;
        }
    }
    myReadFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't read line by line - it reads word by word. If you intend to read lines, you should use `std::string` & `std::getline` a la: `std::string line; std::getline(myReadFile, line); `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to do it unless you know the size of each line through some other means. Then you could add up the sizes of the lines you want to skip and do a `seekg` to skip to the start of the line.

Comment: Those means would most likely involve to step through all the lines ;)

Comment: @m0skit0, if you're doing many random samples into a file it might make sense to read it once just to get the line lengths. Also you might have knowledge of the lengths without reading, i.e. when each line is a fixed length.

Comment: True, I thought that just after posting my comment

Answer (score 4):

In general, no: lines are *delimited* with a special character, your program would need to read all characters, and count the line breaks in order to do what you need.

In special cases when your lines are all of the same length (which happens more often in programming competitions than in practice) you could reposition the file read pointer to a specific place, and read your line from there.

P.S. The only place where I saw it in practice was UUENCODEd files.

Answer (score 2):

> Without having to step through all the lines?

AFAIK, no.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a line in a file you have to understand that line is delimited by a '\n' character. therefore, you will have to read the entire file no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

There's [`seekg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/) that you can use to advance to a particular address within the file.  But unless you can guarantee something about how long each line is, you can't be sure that your random offset actually begins on a new line.

By the way, the given code in the question actually reads one word at a time, not one line at a time.  To read an entire line at once, use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).